# How to pass java function pointer to c++ native code

Tags: java, c++, callback, java-native-interface, swig

I want to call a native c++ method from java (android) code, and pass a java function as a parameter, so I will be able to save the function pointer in the c++ code, and activate it from the native code.

I chose to implement the function pointer in java using anonymous class, and I call the native function from java as following:

```
interface FunctionPtrHelper {
bool function(String param);
```

}

```
NativeFunc(param1,param2,new FunctionPtrHelper() {
public bool myFunction(String param) {
    //body of my function
}});
```

How can I make swig/jni know the 3rd param (which is actually a class) and translate it to a function pointer in c++ (that will contain'myFunction') ?
In case it is not possible, is there another way to pass a function pointer from java to c++?

Comment: I'm not sure JNI works that way. You're calling a native method with jobject as parameter. On that object you can call a method as usual, knowing its name and signature.

Comment: It's also possible to create easily callbacks with [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/#Creating_Callback_Functions). Let me know if you want need more details!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a C++ interface and SWIG it as a "director" class.  Then you can implement the interface in Java.  Instantiate the implementation object in Java and pass it into a C++ method that takes a pointer or reference to the interface, and C++ will be able to call back into your Java class.  For example:

```
// SWIGed C++
class IStringToBool
{
public:
    virtual bool call(std::string s) = 0;
}

class IStringToBoolUser
{
public:
    void setFunction(IStringToBool &function);
}
```

And then:

```
// Java
public class MyFunction implements IStringToBool {
    public bool call(String s) {
        // do something
        return true;
    }
}
```

Documentation: [Cross language polymorphism using directors](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#java_directors)

Answer (score 1):

With JNI you could pass a object to C++, then you could take function pointer from the C++ Object.

Comment: The problem with this is that JNI function pointer (e.g. `CallMethodVoid` etc.) almost certainly doesn't match the function pointer you're looking for in C++. You need to pass in at least `JNIEnv`, the `jobject` and `jmethodID`.