# How to implement observer pattern in C++, calling Java method in JNI

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, observer-pattern, jnienv

I have code that is implementing an observer pattern in C++. I have created Java JNI code that is similar to C++ code to register an observer. When I register an observer in Java, it calls a `native` method that create a listener in C++.

I want the method calls in C++ to call the equivalent methods in my Java observer that is registered. I have created code for this by passing the `JNIEnv` to the observer class in C++, but I've heard this isn't safe. Is there a best practice on this type of implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SWIG](http://swig.org/) directors per the answer to this question: [How to pass java function pointer to c++ native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476429/how-to-pass-java-function-pointer-to-c-native-code)

I would also recommend using SWIG instead of JNI directly.